# How to implement Claim based authorization using Web Api Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization

I am working with Web API and generate JWT token on login. I have a very complex requirement regarding user roles and claims. A user can have multiple roles. A role can have multiple claims and a user can have particular claims. I am using Asp.Net Core Identity. One user can have data in AspNetUserClaims and same user can have different role and each role have claims in AspRoleClaims. I have successfully implemented the Role base authorization using web api but how can I implement claim based authorization in web API?

The one thing that I have already implemented, but don't really like is that I am storing all user claims including claims in the role in a JWT token and on each request I am extracting the claims from the JWT. But is this a best practice or not - Storing large data in JWT token?

Or what is the other way to do claim based authorization in Web API Dot Net core?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom policies like so, you can have multiple individual policies and stack them with authorize tags, or you can have one handler to deal with multiple policies, or in a policy you can have multiple requirements in the
`policyBuilder` (I like this approach for a lot of use cases). See the info below and the microsoft link

an example for registering a custom policy:

**Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
 {
    authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
    "MustBeBornInSummer",
    policyBuilder =>
    {
       //add any other policy requirements here too including ones by default
       //eg policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policyBuilder.AddRequirements(
            new MustBeBornInSummerRequirement()
            //, new AnotherRequirement()
            );
    });
    //only if you want to register as the default policy
    authorizationOptions.DefaultPolicy = authorizationOptions.GetPolicy("MustBeBornInSummer");
});
```

Then in the authorize

Tag you use

```
[Authorize("MustBeBornInSummer")]
```

You can set a default policy either which allows you to use the Authorize tag as normal

```
authorizationOptions.DefaultPolicy = authorizationOptions.GetPolicy("MustBeBornInSummer");
```

**Your requirement class**

```
public class MustBeBornInSummerRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public MustBeBornInSummerRequirement ()
        {
        }
    }
```

**Handler class**

```
 public class MustBeBornInSummerHandler: AuthorizationHandler<MustBeBornInSummerRequirement>
    {

        public MustBeBornInSummerHandler ()
        {
            //your dependency injections
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
            MustBeBornInSummer requirement)
        {  
//Get the claim you want
            var subject = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;

            var dateOfBirth = _useryRepository.GetApplicationUserProfile(subject)?.dob;


           //your logic`check user claims then do stuff, or/and check roles too
            if (!bornInSummer)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }


            // has claims
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

In your configure services you need to register it:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MustBeBornInSummerHandler>();
```

You Can have One handler for multiple requirements too see

```
public class PermissionHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();
        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
          if(requirementMustBeBornInSummer
             //Dostuff continue
          elseIf(requirementIsBlah)
        }
    }
}
```

How to handle claims is up to you, this is how I normally do it

```
var subject = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;

var dateOfBirth = _useryRepository.GetApplicationUserProfile(subject)?.dob;


//My repository
public ApplicationUserProfile GetApplicationUserProfile(string subject)
{
    return _context.ApplicationUserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Subject == subject);
}
```

you can also have individual policies and stack them

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MustBeBornInSummer")]
[Authorize(Policy = "readRole")]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1

As for storing large amounts of data in a JWT, for application specific claims I usually create a table that stores claims for a user in a particular app. I then use the "sub" of the token to look up the claims the user has. This stops you needing to return really large tokens.

Comment: How we add policy in claims?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking? if it is about where to store claims, I just updated my answer

Comment: I am using asp.net identity core.

Comment: How JWT authorize the polices or maybe i don't have clear concept about it

Comment: In the first code block I register the policy in startup, If I dont set it to be the default policy, whenever I want the policy to be used I use the following [Authorize(Policy = "MustBeBornInSummer")]`` in my controller. your handler decides whether the policy conditions are met or not. you do this by `context.Fail();`
                `return Task.CompletedTask;` if the policy conditions arent met or `context.Succeed(requirement);`
            `return Task.CompletedTask;` if the conditions are met

Comment: If i have 50 policy then i need to create 50 classes?

Comment: Thanks. I understand and will let you know about it.

Comment: The one thing i don't like is we need to call database on each API request. If we have 50 different API class and have around 5000 users then it would call db calls many times.

Comment: It depends on how you want to structure your policies, you can put every requirement into one Policy if you wish, I personally dislike that design as it means your policies are likely to be tightly coupled.

Comment: Similar to above it depends on your implementation, you don't need to hit the db for each policy or for each API request. For example you could get claims once then run each policy using the claims or you could store your claims in session. I just provided a very rough example to try give an understanding of different policy based approaches to address your problem, the exact policy you wish to use and the finer points of your implementation are entirely up to you.